# TCP Server high CPU usage

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, tcp, cpu-usage

C# Visual Studio 2013

I'm working on a rough TCP Server/Client.  It works like this:
Client sends message to server > Server sends "response" to client.  I have this in a loop as I'm going to use this transfer of data for multiplayer in a game.  However, I ran a performance test because my TCP Server was using a lot of my CPU when more than three clients connected.  The performance profiler said the following method was responsible for 96% utilization.  Can you help me fix this?

```
private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
    {
        Socket current = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
        int received;

        try
        {
            received = current.EndReceive(AR);
        }
        catch (SocketException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Client forcefully disconnected");
            current.Close(); // Dont shutdown because the socket may be disposed and its disconnected anyway
            _clientSockets.Remove(current);
            return;
        }

        byte[] recBuf = new byte[received];
        Array.Copy(_buffer, recBuf, received);
        string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recBuf);
        Console.WriteLine("Received Text: " + text);


        string msg = "Response!";
        byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);
        current.Send(data);


        current.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _BUFFER_SIZE, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, current);
    }
```

Just in case, here's the AcceptCallback method which calls the ReceiveCallback.

```
private static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
    {
        Socket socket;

        try
        {
            socket = _serverSocket.EndAccept(AR);
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException) // I cannot seem to avoid this (on exit when properly closing sockets)
        {
            return;
        }

        _clientSockets.Add(socket);
        socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _BUFFER_SIZE, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, socket);
        Console.WriteLine("Client connected...");
        _serverSocket.BeginAccept(AcceptCallback, null);
    }
```

Comment: 96% is very good, means that you are not being bogged down by anything else.  Remove the Console.WriteLine() calls.

Comment: The application itself jumps up to 50%+ of my total CPU (8 cores).  I can hear the heatsink fan turn on.  I found a way to keep it under 1% total by using Thread.Sleep(45); however I've heard to never use Thread.Sleep so it feels like a gimmicky solution.

Comment: Well, are you sending data at maximum speed between localhost endpoints? That should drive the CPU to 100%.

Comment: I was, and adding the Thread Sleep delay seemed to fix it.  I just don't feel it's an optimal way of doing it.

Comment: What exactly is your concern? If you try to go as fast as possible then of course you'll be driving CPU to 100%. Why do you want to change that? And how could it possibly be any other way?

Comment: My concern is no longer the CPU usage being high, just the way I managed to keep it down.  I've always read Thread.Sleep should be avoided when possible, so I need a different way of doing it.

Comment: So you want low CPU and less messages per second? You want to throttle the process and go slower?

Comment: That's correct.  The way I did this, in the loop I did Thread.Sleep(45); which is just long enough (45ms) to delay the response so it doesn't eat as much memory and cpu as it wants.  Is this the best way I can "pause" or slow down the thread?

Answer (score 2):

In the comments you say that your code sends data as fast as CPU and network allow but you want to throttle it. You probably should think about what the optimal frequency is that you want to send at. Then, send at that frequency.

```
var delay = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50);
while (true) {
 await Task.Delay(delay);
 await SendMessageAsync(mySocket, someData);
 await ReceiveReplyAsync(mySocket);
}
```

Note, that I have made use of await to untangle the callback mess. If you now add timers or delays into the mix callbacks can get unwieldy. You can do it any way you like, though. Or, you simply use synchronous socket IO on a background thread/task. That is even simpler and the preferred way if there aren't too many threads. Note, that MSDN usually uses the APM pattern with sockets for no good reason.

Note, that Thread.Sleep/Task.Delay are totally fine to use if you want to wait based on time.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you doing this :

```
byte[] recBuf = new byte[received];
Array.Copy(_buffer, recBuf, received);
string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recBuf);
```

You have a copy operation that copies your received buffer in recBuf, and then another one to create the string. You can avoid one and your performance will improve. But the fact that cpu is high is normal because even tranforming to the string will make use of the cpu.

Comment: Are you saying I should GetString from _buffer instead of copying?

Comment: yes, it is an extra copy operation that is a pure waste of cpu power. Get rid of it and use the task delay if you don't want high cpu loads, but the copy operation can be removed and increases efficiency. Please give it a try and upvote if it works.